# How to convert millsec to MYSQL datetime

Tags: mysql

Hi I have date column as a string as below

```
Date
2015-10-08 12:06:00.000
2016-12-10 18:40:25.417
2016-12-10 18:40:25.430
2015-10-08 12:20:00.000
```

I am trying to convert the above column as datetime..

```
select str_to_date (Date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") as Date1 from tab;
```

throwing an error "Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value"

Any modification in the above select statement.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.%f` for the time decimals:

```
select str_to_date (Date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f") as Date1 from tab;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: You're welcome. I should have added though, that you will lose the decimals, as `str_to_date` converts to `datetime` and this data type has no fractions.